Time series plot with event annotations using geom_rect
I have problem with aes(xmin, xmax, fill) in geom_rect function. How to add event_type with geom_rect ? Here is my dummy example.
dummy <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1981-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-01"), by = "month"),
                    Percentage = runif(360, min = 0, max = 100))
dummy$Year <- format(dummy$Date,"%Y")
# Define El Niño, La Niña, and neutral years
el_nino_years <- c(1982, 1987, 1991, 1994, 1997, 2002, 2004, 2009)
la_nina_years <- c(1984, 1988, 1995, 1999, 2000, 2007, 2010)
neutral_years <- setdiff(1981:2010, c(el_nino_years, la_nina_years))
# Create a new column based on the occurrence of El Niño, La Niña, or neutral years
dummy <- dummy %>%
  mutate(event_type = case_when(
    Year %in% el_nino_years ~ "El Niño",
    Year %in% la_nina_years ~ "La Niña",
    Year %in% neutral_years ~ "Neutral",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_  # For years outside the specified range
  ))
dummy_plot <-  ggplot(data = dummy,
      aes(x= Date, y= Percentage))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(
    x = " ",
    y = "Area (%)"
  )+
  theme_minimal()


Hi Rahmat and thank you for your question. 1) Please include a complete example, including library() calls and the problematic code. 2) Please describe the problem you are experiencing. Do you receive an error message or is the formatting wrong? Showing the resulting plot and a sketch of the desired plot might be useful.

Maybe this is the plot you were trying to create with your code.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df_rect <- dummy %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarize(x1=first(Date), x2=last(Date), event_type=first(event_type))

dummy_plot <-  ggplot(data=dummy, aes(x=Date, y=Percentage))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, fill=event_type), 
            ymin=min(dummy$Percentage), ymax=max(dummy$Percentage), 
            alpha=0.2, data=df_rect, inherit.aes=F)+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  labs(x=" ",  y="Area (%)") +
  coord_cartesian(expand=F) +
  theme_minimal() %+replace% theme(legend.position="bottom")


